# Cannot use Direct Update for Windows 8 in Worklight 5.0.6

Tags: windows-8, ibm-mobilefirst

I use Worklight 5.0.6 and can't use direct update for a Windows 8 application.
[IBM Worklight Information Center](http://pic.dhe.ibm.com/infocenter/wrklight/v5r0m6/index.jsp?topic=/com.ibm.worklight.help.doc/admin/c_direct_updates_app_versions_to_desktop.html&resultof=%2522%2564%2569%2572%2565%2563%2574%2522%2520%2522%2575%2570%2564%2561%2574%2565%2522%2520%2522%2575%2570%2564%2561%2574%2522%2520) tells that windows 8 app can use direct update.

My way to test direct update as follows.
Please tell me how to use direct update in Windows8.

1. make windows8 env project
2. change wlInitOptions.connectOnStartup value "true"  (in common\js\initOptions.js )
3. select [Build All and Deploy]
4. double click .jsproj file run simulator in visual studio 2012 for Windows8
5. make app "back ground"
6. change html file and "re [Build All and Deploy]"
7. make app "foreground"

Comment: if your question is answered, please resolve it.

Answer (score 2):

This documentation page is misleading (I will open a defect to correct it).

Direct Update (as in the process of updating the web resources of the application after it has already been installed on the device) is available ONLY for iOS and Android. In those environments following your steps will indeed trigger a Direct Update.

The update (or rather, upgrade) of Desktop applications has no relation what-so-ever to the Direct Update mechanism mentioned above.

For Desktop enviornments consider it like updating any other desktop application - where you up the version number, and the app detects that there is an update available or so.

In the case of Adobe Air and Windows 7/Vista Gadgets:

1. Build your application and install it
2. In application-descriptor.xml, up the value of the `version` attribute in the envrionment's element (for instance from "1.0" to "1.1")
3. Build again
4. I believe that now you need to go to the Worklight Console and re-download the installer, and it will detect that it needs to upgrade rather than install afresh).

Note: iGoogle, Facebook, Windows 7/Vista Gadgets and Dashboard environments will be removed in the next version of Worklight. All have ample replacements with other supported Worklight environments.

In the case of Windows 8:

- Direct Update most certainly does not exist for it
- The steps above are also not relevant as it is not a downloadable executable